# How to type click event document?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### typescript code

```js
    type PopupClick = MouseEvent & {
            path: Node[];
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            const _event = event as PopupClick;
            console.log(_event);
            if (
                selectorRef.current &&
                !_event.path.includes(selectorRef.current)
            ) {
                setIsVisible(false);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
    }, []);
```

### error text

```
const handleClickOutside: (event: MouseEvent) => void
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "click", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.ts(2769)
```

**Tried**

- MouseEvent
- MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>
- Mouse event

Nothing I found helped, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

On the parent div, add an `onClick` attribute:

```
<div onClick={handleClickOutside}>
  {/* Other elements here */}
</div>
```

Then move the `handleClickOutside` function out of the `useEffect` block.

Comment: But here such situation that it is necessary to hang up on the document. (This is a toolbar in a separate component)

Comment: sorry, I just recently noticed that there was a mention of a div in the title.